# Why is there no baseclass in the sample located \Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\plus

Tags: android, google-plus, google-api-client

This sample projects trying to connect to the Google+ for authentication. e.g

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, options)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
```

on every class in the method `onCreate`. This could have been easily done by using a baseclass and then codding the above code in the base class's `onCreate` method.

Similarly, all the code for `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` , `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`.

Could there have been a specific reason for not doing so ?

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent reason for not doing this. Java does not support multiple inheritance, so by creating a base class that handles all of this, Google would be significantly limiting your options when integrating Google APIs.

Not everyone does or wants to consume Google APIs within an `Activity`, for example. If Google were to create a `BaseGoogleApiActivity`, anyone using Google APIs in a class that extends something else (e.g. a `Fragment` or a `Service`) can't use that base class. Furthermore, there are myriad variants of the three classes I've mentioned here (`ListActivity`, `ListFragment`, `AppCompatActivity`, `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, just to name a few), so trying to create base classes for each of these is not a trivial task, with little reward. And we haven't even started talking about using Google APIs in non-Android-framework classes.

At the end of the day, it makes much more sense to provide the Google APIs without creating a base class, as it makes the Google API client much more flexible.

*Note: this is just one possible reason for making this decision. There are many more arguments both for and against making creating a base class for this functionality, but to me this is the biggest one.*